# Java assignment don't know what is the mistake

Tags: java

the question is :

A fruit shop sells several types of fruits each day. Write a program that reads from user several lines of input.Each line includes a fruit's name,price per kilogram (as an integer), number of kilograms sold (as an integer).

the program should calculate and print the earned money of all fruits sold and fruit that achieved largest profit.

hint: -you could assume that user will insert valid data -user could stop the program via entering the word "stop" as a fruit's name.

Sample input and out put:

in each line, insert a fruit's name, price per kilogram, number of kilograms sold. To halt the program,insert "stop" as a fruit's name

---

banana 2 11 
mango 3 8 
peach 4 5

stop

---

the earned money of all fruits sold: 66 
fruit that achieved the largest profit: mango

---

what i wrote now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
// TODO code application logic here 
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
String fruitname= " "; 
String maxfruit = " "; 
int price = 0,number=0; 
int sum=0; 
int max=0; 


System.out.print("Fruit name, " + "price in killogram, number of killogram sold: "); 

while (!fruitname.equals("stop")) 
{ 
fruitname = input.next(); 
price = input.nextInt(); 
number = input.nextInt(); 
} 
if (fruitname.equals("stop")) 
{ 
sum = sum+(price*number); 

} 
if (max<(price*number)) 
{ 
max = price*number; 
maxfruit = fruitname; 
} 


System.out.println("the earned money of all fruits is " + sum); 
System.out.println("fruit that achieved the largest profit is "+ maxfruit); 
} 
}
```

the program is not reading what i submit to it, don't know why and not giving me the sum and the max fruit.. what is the problem of what i wrote?

Comment: what is the problem ? Exception, wrong output, wrong color, wrong name, wrong song ?

Comment: when i run it, it is not reading the fruitname the price and the number of kilograms the user types, so it doesn't submit the sum of all of them.

Comment: but what do you mean by not reading ? I am asking because I think it's important for you to be able to understand the source of the problem;

Comment: I think that even if it reads your input that program will satisfies all the requests.

Comment: like i type for example: peach 2 2 (press enter) it doesn't loop and ask me about the fruit again (which it should) and if i type stop it the program doesn't stop and gives me the values.

Comment: Look again at your while loop. It just reads the data but does not do anything with it. (Hint: this is not the only error in the program)

Comment: @Henry how do i fix it then?

Comment: You got already so many hints (also on your other question that got closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939550/cant-solve-a-java-program-assignment); It's now time for you to try something on your own.

Comment: ...... i already took those hints into consideration and still faced another current problem, (still have no idea why it was closed), i already tried on my own, why would i be here if i figured it out on my own already?

Comment: @user2984981 Obviously you are learning how to program. One of the skills you have to master is to debug faulty programs. You could start with a desk check or run it with a debugger to find out what is going on. We won't do you a favor if we just write your program.

Comment: @Henry i am not asking anyone to write me a fresh program, i already posted mine and just wanted to know what am i doing wrong, don't want someone to write me a fresh new one that i could just copy paste that would not help me at all (yes i am a beginner and don't even know what a debugger is) and every one that answered me now helped me a lot in understanding my mistake and currently fixing them.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see your reads happen in the `while` loop:

```
while (!fruitname.equals("stop")) 
{ 
    fruitname = input.next(); 
    price = input.nextInt(); 
    number = input.nextInt(); 
}
```

Every time it loops - it overrides the values. Finally when you read stop and exit the loop - your `fruitname` is **stop**. So you need to fix your logic on how you would want to read in the input

Comment: Just to add to this, you can use a `String array` and put in the values in there till `stop` is entered.

Answer (score 1):

Working variant:

```
public class FruitTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Fruit name, " + "price in killogram, number of killogram sold: ");

    String text = input.nextLine();

    String[] words = text.split(" ");

    List<Fruit> fruits = parseInput(words);

    int sum = getSum(fruits);

    String popular = getPopularFruitName(fruits);

    System.out.println("Got fruits: " + fruits.toString());
    System.out.println("the earned money of all fruits is " + sum);
    System.out.println("fruit that achieved the largest profit is " + popular);
}

private static String getPopularFruitName(List<Fruit> fruits) {
    int max = 0;
    String name = null;

    for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
        int checkVal = fruit.getPrice() * fruit.getAmount();
        if(checkVal > max) {
            max  = checkVal;
            name = fruit.getName();
        }
    }

    return name;
}

private static int getSum(List<Fruit> fruits) {
    int result = 0;
    for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
        result += fruit.getPrice() * fruit.getAmount();
    }
    return result;
}

private static List<Fruit> parseInput(String[] words) {
    List<Fruit> result = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    int element = 1;
    final int name = 1;
    final int price = 2;
    final int amount = 3;

    Fruit fruit = null;
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.equals("stop") || word.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        if(element > amount)
            element = name;

        switch (element) {
            case name:
                fruit = new Fruit(word);
                result.add(fruit);
                break;
            case price:
                if (fruit != null) {
                    fruit.setPrice(Integer.valueOf(word));
                }
                break;
            case amount:
                if(fruit != null) {
                    fruit.setAmount(Integer.valueOf(word));
                }
                break;
        }
        element++;
    }

    return result;
}

static class Fruit {
    String name;
    int price  = 0;
    int amount = 0;


    Fruit(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ". $" + price +
               ", amount=" + amount;
    }
}
}
```

Comments to code - it's proper way to parse all the inputted string and parse it to an object that stores all the data - name, price and amount. Store all parsed objects into array or a list and then calculate max and popular fruit while looping your parsed fruit array

Answer (score 0):

I found some mistake. The most important was in the while condition. Check this out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    // TODO code application logic here 
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
    String fruitname = null;
    String maxfruit = null;
    int fruitSum = 0;
    int totalSum = 0; 
    int max = 0; 

    System.out.print("Fruit name, " + "price in killogram, number of killogram sold: "); 


    while(!(fruitname = input.next()).equals("stop")){
        fruitSum = input.nextInt() * input.nextInt();
        totalSum += fruitSum;
        if(fruitSum > max){
            maxfruit = fruitname;
            max = fruitSum;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("the earned money of all fruits is " + totalSum); 
    System.out.println("fruit that achieved the largest profit is "+ maxfruit); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh it is reading it.

the problem is that it doesn't do what you want it to do.

the problems with the code I can see are this:

- you are not storing the fruits quantities or prices anywhere, you need to store the values
  in an array or something (maxFruit,MaxValue) to compare them later.
- when you are reading the fruit values and a "stop" string is input the next step in your  code is to wait for the price so it won't get out of the loop even if you input "stop", you need to restructure your scanner loop.

And if it is a beginner class it may be ok, but the code you are writing is not object oriented don't write the logic in the main.

You may want to learn to debug it is a very useful tool when you are learning to code, if you run this program in debug mode , you could see that the values are getting input and everything that is happening, Netbeans and Eclipse have very good debuggers and it would be worth to expend half an hour learning the basics of debugging It certainly helped me a lot when I was starting.

Comment: He doesn't need an array, he just has to store the total sum and the global maximum.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FruitSells {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        BufferedReader bufer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String str;
            String[] inarr;
            int sumMoney = 0;
            do {
                str = (String) bufer.readLine();
                inarr = str.split(" ");
                for(int i = 1; i < inarr.length; i += 3) {
                    sumMoney += Integer.parseInt(inarr[i]) * Integer.parseInt(inarr[i + 1]);
                }
                System.out.println(sumMoney);
                sumMoney = 0;
            } while (!str.equals("stop"));


        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problems with bufer.readLine()");
        }
    }
}
```

something like this you can modernize it.sorry for eng i can not speak))and write correctly of course))

Comment: It's best if you can outline exactly what the issue with the question asker's code was. Just letting them copy and paste is not going to help them in the long run.

Comment: @MamedKhazri why do you randomnly insert the ')' symbol randomly in your comments and answers?